# Twilio - Is there a way to bypass voicemail

Tags: twilio

I have a twilio app that provides an on-call list of phone numbers that our customer's can call and speak to one of our on-support developers.

I need to find a solution that will allow the caller to press a key to bypass the voicemail of a the calling party and be redirected to the next person in the on-call list. Right now, if I call my twilio app using my number and I get the calling party voicemail, I don't have an option to move onto the next person in the call list.

Is there a way to mimic the hangupOnStar feature when a caller gets a person voicemail in twilio?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had a look into this and unfortunately it does not look like you can nest `<Dial>` within `<Gather>` otherwise this might be possible.

What I would recommend is when you receive an inbound call, play a message along the lines of "Please wait a moment while we connect an available developer", then `<Enqueue>` the call.

At this point your application can start calling the developers and when the line connects ask them to press #, when this happens you can `<Dial>` the developers call into the queue ID Twilio proved in the last call to you app, and the calls will be bridged. If the developer did not press # then you can assume that it went to voicemail, at which point `<Hangup>` and initiate a call to the next dev on call.

Hope that helps.